# CoreData sorted entities - performance

Tags: ios, core-data, ios5, ios4

I would like to have my CoreData entities stored in a sorted array/set, so that I don't have to sort it every time in a fetch using `NSSortDescriptor`. In iOS 4 and below, I believe this is my only option, but sorting the entire data set (not just the fetched results) every time - that sounds terribly inefficient, even for a relatively small data set of ~10k.

In iOS 5 there are sorted sets; I wonder if the performance gain is enough to warrant dropping iOS 4 support? Any experiences to be shared?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to sort the results - you can do your fetch and pass sortOrderings to the fetch. If you need to traverse a relationship, you can add a method of your own on the parent that does a raw fetch on the child, has a predicate added where the parent relationship is self, add your own sort orderings and returns a nice NSArray :)

I mean hey, if you can force iOS5, great, but if you need to keep iOS 4 around, letting the database do the sorting is very performant.